# Parameterized queries dealing with Views are not supported

Tags: google-bigquery

```
Create View db.test_1 as select * from db.test where yr=@yr;
```

Running this query is BQ CLI would create the view but when you query this view, execution fails with exception that parameters are not supported.
Any insight of doing it?

Comment: "parameterized Views are not supported" - you can find respective feature request on issue tracker or file your own if needed

Comment: Normally "parameterized views" is another way of saying table-valued functions. [This is the feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905221).

Comment: Thank you Mikhail and Elliott.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard can you please add your response as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to create a view that takes parameters, also known as a table-valued function. There is [an open feature request on the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905221) to support this functionality, however, and you can follow it for updates.